# Layout issue in Feed Activity of Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

[image: android relativelayout layout_weight]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: htc
- Device Model: Nexus 9

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (2960889)

Activity is missing `layout_weight` in `<RelativeLayout>` from `GroupView` for `JUST NOW`,`EARLIER TODAY`,etc.